# How to fill one combo box based an other selected combo box value by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, combobox

i want to fill a combobox options based on another selected combobox option
keep in mind that i have php code in the same page

```
    <select name="idcataloguectg" class="form-control" id="idcataloguectg">
    <!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
    <?php
    try
    {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mywsite_db;charset=utf8', 'root', '');// connection to the server and DB
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
                die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());// if error
        }
        $respond = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM catalogue');// my request

        while ($data = $respond->fetch())// fetch into the table
        {
        ?>
        <!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
<option value="<?php echo $data['0']; ?>"><?php echo $data['1']; ?></option>
        <!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
        <?php
        }
        $respond->closeCursor(); // end of request
        ?>
        <!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
    </select>
    <label>Categorie</label><br>
    <select name="idcategorief" class="form-control" id="idcategorief">
        <!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
        <?php
        $idcataloguectg = $_GET['idcataloguectg'];
        try
        {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mywsite_db;charset=utf8', 'root', '');// connection to the server and DB
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
                die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());// if error
        }
        $respond = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM categorie WHERE id_categorie='.$idcataloguectg.'');// my request

        while ($data = $respond->fetch())// fetch into the table
        {
        ?>
        <!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
<option value="<?php echo $data['0']; ?>"><?php echo $data['2']; ?></option>
        <!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
        <?php
        }
        $respond->closeCursor(); // end of request
        ?>
        <!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
</select>
```

i tried to search for examples but all i found that they use an external php file that fill the options but in my example i have all of them in the same page
so what can i do
can you gives me the ajax script

Comment: First please indent your source code, second; you don't need to open a connection before each statement.

Answer (score 0):

For the second `select` field to change accordingly, you need to reload the page when the user changes the value of the category select field. To do that, change the select tag to

```
<select name="idcataloguectg" class="form-control" id="idcataloguectg" onChange="window.location.href = '/?idcataloguectg=' + this.value">
```

This will change the url to the same site (you may need to replace the `/` with the name of your php file), but with the `idcataloguectg` `GET` parameter set correctly.

If you do that, you might also want to change the option line for the categories to

```
<option value="<?php echo $data['0']; ?>" <?php if ($_GET['idcataloguectg'] == $data['0']) { ?> selected <?php } ?>><?php echo $data['1']; ?></option>
```

So that when a category was selected through the `GET` parameter, the right option is selected, instead of the default (first) one.

---

But it isn't a good idea to reload the whole page, instead you should do it with ajax, but that requieres you to put the logic for the second `select` tag in another file, for example `category.php`. That file should contain the following (that portion of the code would obiously be removed from the main file):

```
<!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
<?php
$idcataloguectg = $_GET['idcataloguectg'];
try
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mywsite_db;charset=utf8',     'root', '');// connection to the server and DB
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());// if error
}
$respond = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM categorie WHERE  id_categorie='.$idcataloguectg.'');// my request

while ($data = $respond->fetch())// fetch into the table
{
?>
<!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
                                              <option value="<?php echo     $data['0']; ?>"><?php echo $data['2']; ?></option>
<!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
<?php
}
$respond->closeCursor(); // end of request
?>
<!--  PHP CODE ##################################### -->
```

Then change the first `select` tag to

```
<select name="idcataloguectg" class="form-control" id="idcataloguectg" onChange="$.get('category.php?idcataloguectg=' + this.value, function(data){$('#idcategorief').html(data);});">
```

The script uses jQuery and sends a request to the new php file `category.php`, with the category id as a `GET` parameter. When the request returns successfully with the options, they are places inside the second `select` tag, replacing the previous contents.

This has the benefit of only sending the needed data every time, reducing the traffic  and computing needed drastically.

EDIT:

I put the js in the `onChange` attribute of the `select` tag. This code gets executed every time the selected value changes. You can also put the code in a script tag or file inside a function and then execute the function in the atribute.
I use the `$.get` function from jQuery for the ajax calls, which is a shorthand for the `$.ajax` function with a simple syntax. Read up on them [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

The script I used is the following:

```
$.get(
    'category.php?idcataloguectg=' + this.value,
    function(data){
        $('#idcategorief').html(data);
    }
);
```

It starts an `GET` ajax request to the file "category.php" with the get parameter `idcataloguectg` set and defines a callback function on success, which takes the response data and replaces the innerhtml of the second select tag with it.
But it is better to write like this:

```
$.get(
    'category.php',
    {
        idcataloguectg: $('#idcataloguectg').val()
    },
    function(data){
        $('#idcategorief').html(data);
    }
);
```

This does  the same, but defines the parameters in an object, which is more readable and also works with `POST` requests. Also, I replaced the `this` with a jQuery selector based on the `id`, because the `this` can betricky at times, so this is safer.

If you would want to have three select tags, the first can stay the same and the second script (which is called by the `onChange` attribute of the second `select` tag) would need to look like this:

```
$.get(
    'second.php',
    {
        valueSelectOne: $('#idOfFirstSelectTag').val(),
        valueSelectTwo: $('#idOfSecondSelectTag').val()
    },
    function(data){
        $('#idThirdSelectTag').html(data);
    }
);
```

replace `second.php` with the name of your php file, which return the values for the third input field and the id's accordingly. If you don't understand something related to the `$`, you should read up on jQuery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you maybe gives me an example for the ajax script
and if i had 3 comboboxes and i did this method to 2 how to fill the third

Comment: Edited my answer